# Terraform kubernetes_namespace for Openshift

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, openshift

I'm creating a resource with terraform. My company gave access to the projects api. So I can run `oc new-project aa`, but I don't have access to the namespace API. So, I can't run `oc create namespace aa`.

My terraform resource looks like:

```
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "atlas-project" {
  metadata {
    annotations = {
      "openshift.io/description"  = "A dashboard and upcoming CD to manage Prometheus alerts"
      "openshift.io/display-name" = "Atlas"
    }
    name = "atlas"
  }
}
```

I get the same error that I do when using OC.

> │ Error: v1 "namespaces" is forbidden: User "bkauffman7k2030" cannot
> create v1 at the cluster scope: no RBAC policy matched

I also tried using the openshift provider with openshift_project and get:

> │ Error: projects.project.openshift.io is forbidden: User "bkauffman7k2030" cannot create projects.project.openshift.io at the cluster scope: no RBAC policy matched

Is there any way I can change the resource to use a different api?

**The oc command uses the projectrequests api**

Comment: I think your options are (a) ask for access to the namespace api, (b) create the project manually with `oc` rather than with terraform, or (c) write a custom provider that works the same was as the `oc` command.

Comment: You dont have RBAC permissions to create namespaces. You'll have to ask for the admin to provide elevated privileges